# Incorrect/unreadable cyrillic file names in archives, maked from ubuntu server 14.04.2

Tags: cyrillic

When i make a file "тест.txt" compressed with gz, file name is unreadable for windows PC (7zip, HaoZip, etc), but for linux is OK.

When compress is bz2 file names are OK.

When compress is zip - then mess is full
[image]

Comment: I think the reason is UTF-8 encoding used in zip module.
If use a different app to extract - BandiZip (supports UTF-8 encoding), the names are readable again.
BUT in ZIP file is included a full path to files, which is a big problem.